# Remove the brackets when saved in Database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am saving an arraylist in my database. But what happens when I saved it, is this:

[image]

I want to remove the brackets from the data of the last column and I want my database to be like this one:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j=0; j<checkSelected.length; j++) {
        if(checkSelected[j]==true) {
            String values = BrandListAdapter.mListItems.get(j);
            Cursor rSubBrand = databaseHandler.getReport_SubBrandCode(values);
            String SubBrandCode = rSubBrand.getString(rSubBrand.getColumnIndex(Constants.SUBBRAND_CODE));
            content.clear();
            content.add(SubBrandCode);

            String subBrand = content.toString();

            databaseHandler.SaveSubBrand(new Cons_iReport (ReportCode, subBrand));
    }                       
}
```

Comment: you can parse the string in this code and remove the brackets

Comment: You can do a subBrand.replaceAll("[","") and subBrand.replaceAll("]","")

Comment: Hi @AlvinArulselvan, I tried your code but there was an error: 'java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 1'

Comment: Have you tried a normal subBrand.replace('[','') and subBrand.replace(']','')?A .replaceAll uses a regex pattern which seems to be confused by the brackets

Comment: "[" and "]" are considered as special character, try to escape them: `subBrand.replaceAll("\[","");`

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan, there's no changes when I used replace()

Comment: @shoerat, it's invalid escape sequence. Valid ones are \b, \t, \', \", \\. That's why I can't used your suggestion

Comment: subBrand.replaceAll("\\\[","") and subBrand.replaceAll("\\\]","") should work...nasty escape characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure it out. The reason why I cannot remove the brackets is because I didn't assigned it to the 'subBrand' that will be saved to the database.

```
ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int j=0; j<checkSelected.length; j++) {
        if(checkSelected[j]==true) {
            String values = BrandListAdapter.mListItems.get(j);
            Cursor rSubBrand = databaseHandler.getReport_SubBrandCode(values);
            String SubBrandCode = rSubBrand.getString(rSubBrand.getColumnIndex(Constants.SUBBRAND_CODE));
            content.clear();
            content.add(SubBrandCode);

            String subBrand = content.toString();
            subBrand = subBrand.replace("[", ""); // this is what I mean...
            subBrand = subBrand.replace("]", "");

            databaseHandler.SaveSubBrand(new Cons_iReport (ReportCode, subBrand));
        }                       
    }
```

Comment: Great that you solved it.You could make your variables easier to understand so that you know which to save to db and which is just a holding variable.Comments help too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replaceAll function:

`subBrand = subBrand.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");`

that replaces all brackets found in the string.